# Heroku postgres connection in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I have tried to connect to postgres the same way I connect to phpmyadmin but it seems that the connection  fails.. What I did was to copy and paste my credentials into the php file.. I was wondering if i need to activate the postgres database before trying to connect?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Best..

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Exact error message text?

Comment: For future questions please read the FAQ, particularly http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: A really good read for asking questions on any forum: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

What error message do you get?

You need to at least add the database to your app before it will be available - [see this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246014/28037). Have you been able to add the app and see the database credentials?