# Database name & user & password & host on heroku

Tags: php, sql, heroku

I want to install a php script with a database on heroku. How I can get the database name, password, user, and host information for the database I install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several different databases available on Heroku - you can view the options and add them to your app at [addons.heroku.com](https://addons.heroku.com/). Probably the first/most basic database is Postgres - [here is the heroku Postgres tutorial](https://addons.heroku.com/). Quoted from the [relevant section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#connecting-and-using-database-urls):

> Each database installed on a Heroku app has a unique database URL which can be used by your app to connect to that database. Database URLs take the format postgres://username:password@host:port/database_name.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, each app has a DATABASE_URL config var; this is the the database that represents your default database.

Heroku [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) are set as environment variables when your app is created. Thus you can probably read the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to get the information you need to connect to your database.

Comment: and which the best database can i use it ??

Comment: @Deejay Which database is best probably depends on your needs, and is probably a good topic to research or its own SO Question.

Comment: Thank you mr. Culix